# PHP/ MySQL Query: Rows Not Being Inserted

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a large SQL file I'm trying to insert into the database.  It wouldn't work via phpMyAdmin since it was so large, so I created a custom script:

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

$file = file_get_contents('./mySQLfile.sql');

//var_dump($file); die();

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'myUserName', 'myPassword', 'myDatabase');

$q = $file;

if ($result = $conn->query($q))
{
    echo '<font color="red">'.$conn->error.'</font>';
    echo '<br />';
}

?>
```

The file var_dump()'s properly.  The connection to the database is created (I've tested it by returning values from the database).  However, when I run the code, no data is inserted into the database.  The beginning of the SQL file is as follows:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Dec 05, 2012 at 04:01 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.16
-- PHP Version: 5.3.8

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `myDatabase`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `content_field_image_cache`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `content_field_image_cache` (
  `vid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `field_image_cache_fid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_image_cache_list` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_image_cache_data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vid`,`delta`),
  KEY `nid` (`nid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `content_field_image_cache`
--

INSERT INTO `content_field_image_cache` (`vid`, `nid`, `delta`, `field_image_cache_fid`, `field_image_cache_list`, `field_image_cache_data`) VALUES
(1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 1, NULL),
(1001, 1001, 0, 1001, 1, NULL),
(1002, 1002, 0, 1002, 1, NULL),
```

Why won't these values get inserted?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the exact size of your sql file?

Comment: Run unbuffered queries instead. Because statements `DELETE`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` do not return value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's mysql driver (mysql/mysqli/pdo) doesn't allow multiple queries in a single call as a security measure. You cannot feed an entire dump into a single query call like that.

You'd be better off simply doing something like

```
exec("mysql -u xxx -p < dump.sql");
```

instead.

Comment: I have googled but am not sure of the syntax here.  Can you put it in context of "myUsername," "myPassword," "myDatabase?"  Also, is there another way to do this if the `exec` command is not available?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have command line access, this is a shared server.  Can I use the help command via PHP script in my web browser?  If so, how?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the syntax here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html

Comment: It still is not working and it's not giving me any error.  What can I do to see why it's not working?  I already added `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` to the top of the script.

Comment: Update:  `exec('whoami');` works so `exec` works, but not `mysql`.  Would there be another way to access it?

Comment: mysql may not be in the path of the shell that exec is using. try a fullblown `/usr/bin/mysql`-type path, adjusting to match your system's setup, of course.